# How to change my function to work with PHP 5.2

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array:

```
Array(
    [0] => Array(
        [Success] => The file was uploaded.
    )[1] => Array(
        [Error] => The file doesn 't exist.
    )[2] => Array(
        [Success] => The file is supported.
    )
)
```

How can I loop in this array to echo something like this:

```
Success = The file was uploaded
```

I have tried it with:

```
foreach($results as $innerArr) {
  array_keys($innerArr)[0];
}
```

Which works fine on a current PHP Version. But because I have PHP 5.2 and can't change it, it doesn't work.

Function return value dereferencing was only added in 5.4.

Comment: And your problem/question is...?

Comment: How can I solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do this prior to 5.4:

```
array_keys($innerArr)[0];
```

So:

```
$foo = array_keys($innerArr);
$bar = $foo[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php):

> As of PHP 5.4 it is possible to array dereference the result of a
>   function or method call directly. Before it was only possible using a
>   temporary variable.

This means, if you are using a Version `< PHP 5.4`, you need to save the result of `array_keys` in a variable first:

```
foreach($results as $result) {
    $keys = array_keys($result);
    echo $keys[0] . ' = ' . $result[0];
}
```